# Link to "name" in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I'm having an unexpected behavior with links to the same page in Codeigniter. Somewhere in the page is a  tag.

However, links such as

```
<a href="#xx"></a>
```

are not working. Even if I enter the URL manually:

```
"path/to/page#xx" or "path/to/page/#xx"
```

it goes to the top of the page.

Something to do with the fact that there are no filename in the URL? Any clue will be welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post your tags as well?

Comment: please provide the html tag.  Also you can do the same by javascript.

Comment: Sorry I deleted it by mistake. Please check the comments in the answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably has nothing at all to do with CodeIgniter.  Make sure you have either of these:

**1. Standard Anchor** `<a name="xx">XX</a>`, or...

**2. An element with "xx" as the ID** `<div id="xx">...</div>`

I can't imagine what CI would be doing to throw you off here...

Comment: Well, the tag was something like <h1 name="xx"></h1> and there's no other element with the same id.

Comment: However, I don't know where I took from the idea of making the link to an <H> tag... oops! Thank you all!

Comment: Linking to a heading tag is fine, you just need the **id** to be "xx" rather than the **name** attribute.